# How to get only real users using Microsoft Graph

Tags: active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

When I use Microsoft Graph to retrieve users I get all types of users back, including service accounts. I am looking at a way to only get real persons back just the same list as is displayed in MS Outlook, Teams etc?

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you are after [`People API`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-people?view=graph-rest-1.0), for example:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/people
```

which returns

> a collection of person objects ordered by their relevance to the user,
>   which is determined by the user's communication and collaboration
>   patterns, and business relationships.

Also a [`List orgContacts` endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/orgcontact-list?view=graph-rest-beta) could be utilized which returns:

> the list of organizational contacts for this organization

but it is only available at the moment under the `/beta` API version.

Example:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/contacts
```

Comment: Thanks Vadim, that looks to be exactly what I need.